# Scrape table from webpage into a DataFrame using read_html

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I'm trying to do some webscraping but it keeps showing no tables found but there is literally a table on the website. Maybe I'm not writing the right code. Someone help. Here is the link to the website.  [Film-Locations-in-San-Francisco](https://data.sfgov.org/Culture-and-Recreation/Film-Locations-in-San-Francisco/yitu-d5am/data)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni2bu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MY75.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the code you have tried so far? It would help your question if you researched how to properly format it. Also, there are plenty of posts out there already about scraping HTML tables in Python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using `requests`. But you should note that the `requests` does not receive the table because the table is generated after rendering the page and it is not exists in the `requests` data. A basic way is to use something like `Selenium` to first load the page then retrieve the information.

Based on your comment use something similar to:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/Users/user/Desktop/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://data.sfgov.org/Culture-and-Recreation/Film-Locations-in-San-Francisco/yitu-d5am/data")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="renderTypeContainer"]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/table')
elem.text
#driver.close()
```

Comment: This is the code I used 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MY75.png

Comment: This does not work? I will try to develop a version with selenium.

Comment: Look at the answer again.